# Google Maps v2 not loading on some devices

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Google Maps Api v2 for android. I use com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView in android.support.v4.app.Fragment. My code works fine on Samsung Galaxy S4(Android 4.4.2) and Nexus 5(Android 4.4.4), but don't work in Samsung Galaxy S Duos(4.2.2) and Samsung Galaxy Note 1. On Samsung Galaxy S Duos i receive this messages on logcat

I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

Cant find any solution for this.

Comment: create the signed application use the new debug keystore to generate the google map key. try this.

Comment: I tried and its work for me... Its strange, because I have created new debug keystore yesterday and it work for other devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create the signed application and use the new debug keystore to generate the google map key

Comment: I don't understand this answer. What "new debug keystore"? I already have a debug keystore. Can you elaborate more?